# Subprocess is not running Sikuli with pytest

Tags: subprocess, pytest, sikuli

I try to launch a Sikuli test within Pytest.
My goal is to handle a PKCS12 Chrome alert by clicking "OK".

To do so, I run a subprocess calling the Sikuli JAR with the Sikuli test as an argument.
The subprocess call is valid with Python 3.8 as it is running fine in the Python idle.
But in the pytest process, there's no clue the subprocess is doing anything and the test finishes with a timeout exception.

Any idea about what i am missing ?

**My context :**

- Windows 7
- Python 3.8
- Pytest 5.2.2
- Sikuli 2.0.0 (running with OpenJDK 9)

**My code :**

```py
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def test_webaccess():
    options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://<my_website_url>/")
    time.sleep(10)
    subprocess.run('java -jar %SIKULI%/sikulix-2.0.0.jar -r <path_to_sikuli_test>/click_ok.py', shell=True, capture_output=True)
    assert "<webiste_title>" in driver.title
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The get command is waiting a HTTP response.
So, the subprocess is never running.

To do so, you need to use *multiprocessing*.

The solution code :

```py
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Process

def clik_ok():
    subprocess.run('java -jar %SIKULI%/sikulix-2.0.0.jar -r <path_to_sikuli_test>/click_ok.py', shell=True, capture_output=True)

def test_sdc_webaccess():
    options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    p=Process(target=clik_ok)
    p.start()
    driver.get("<my_website_url>")
    p.join()
    assert "<webiste_title>" in driver.title
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    driver.close()
```